# ReactJS get JSON from Laravel localhost xhr.js error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, httprequest

I'm using laravel 5.8 with xampp. My laravel files in the xampp/htdocs folder and my React files in the any desktop folder *(so laravel is running xampp, react is running npm.)*.

You know react use default port 3000, I'm using  config for laravel. The *etc/host* file is also configured.

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/son_surum/public"
  ServerName local.laravel58
</VirtualHost>
```

I can fetch data from external links (github etc.). But I couldn't fetch from http://local.laravel58/ URL.

**Laravel response code** *The browser is also working, already GET request method.*

```
<?php
..
return response($allPosts,200)->header('Content-Type','application/json');
```

**React fetch with axios code**

```
componentDidMount() {
    //axios.get('http://local.laravel58/react/all-posts')
    axios.get('http://local.laravel58/react/all-posts')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
            this.setState({ posts: res.data });
        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("----",(error)) //postCard.js line #25
    });
 }
```

Error show like this;

[image: fetch error]

I couldn't solve that. Normally, It should fetching data. Maybe problem is port ? or apache (httpd.conf) ? Despite my research, I couldn't find a solution.

Thank you for interest.

Best regards..

Comment: on your network console, what is the status code and the body of your request ?

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer, I solved. Problem has been at the CORS. Again sorry for being in a hurry :/

Comment: nice you have solve your issue, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh sorry, I solve this quickly with CORS. I was add laravel response to header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

**laravel code thats like change**

```
<?php
..
return response($allPosts,200)
            ->header('Content-Type','application/json')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

I apologize for being in a hurry. Wishing it to be useful.

Best regards.